# Как добавить функцию сворачивания (скрытия) части текста в vim, Как в VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

Очень понравилась функция сворачивания части кода в редакторе VScode. Как добавить ее в Vim?
[image: До сворачивания header]

[image: После]

Искал в гугле, но не нашел ничего подобного.

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding

Answer (score 2):

Это должен делать плагин, который поддерживает синтаксис. Попробуйте установить вручную:

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax.
```

Comment: Немного не то, на что я расчитывал. Но укащали в каком направлении двигатся спасибо